# Adding a new row in between the two rows of the datagridview c#

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

[image: Datagridview display]

what i am trying a do is that if the user clicks for example a button placed in the "random" row then a new row appears at run time in between the "random" and the "string" in the [stringtext] column..the user can add only the "stringtext" and after adding the row each datagridview row is increased by one row..any ideas?

Comment: A small hint, look for DataGridView.Rows.Insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PPUTDG.Rows.Insert(rowIndex, count);
```

Could be what you are looking for?

Comment: That kind of solves my one problem but how to add i make a row appear at runtime?any ideas?

Comment: As soon as you do the insert command, it should appear. So I'm going to assume you mean after you close and reopen the application?

Answer (score 0):

To insert the row :

```
dataGrid.Rows.Insert(indexWhereToInsertTheRow, values, toPopulate, theRow);
```

To make it appear at runtime :

```
dataGrid.Refresh();
```